# Не могу определиться с IT-профессией

Tags: python, веб-программирование, разработка-игр, любой-язык, мобильные-приложения

Здарова. Я не могу определиться с тем, что мне конкретно нравится в программировании. Меня привлекает, казалось бы, всё. Меня привлекает разработка игр под андроид, разработка мобильных приложений. Меня также привлекают нейросети и искуственный интеллект. Но одно я знаю точно: меня не привлекает создание сайтов и веб-приложений.
Более того мне нравятся несколько языков и также я не могу определиться с выбором тут: C++, C#, Python, Java — вот мои претенденты. Можете подсказать, как определиться с выбором, были ли Вы в такой ситуации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да вы уже утомили с такими вопросами на СО. Монету подбросьте.

Comment: А для какой цели вы определяетесь ? Если что, переквалифицироваться и пойти на другой проект, даже с незнакомым языком. обычно проблем не составляет

Answer (score 5):

Да легко! :

```py
from random import choice

print(choice("C++, C#, Python, Java".split(", ")))
# Python
```

Comment: Автор не может за себя решить "что ему нравиться". Вот представьте, использует он ваш скрипт, выучить "не тот" язык, на работу не возьмут, жена сбежит, жизнь пойдет под откос.  Кто будет виноват? -  Разумеется тот, кто ему подсунул этот скрипт! Не автор-же вопроса, а автор скрипта, который строки не в нужном порядке указал.        А если серьезно -  автор, если вы не можете понять, что из перечисленного вам больше нравиться, то может лучше переключиться на что-то другое, в мире так много профессий. Зачем зацикливаться на ИТ?

Comment: @passant, я заранее подумал об этом - виноват будет генератор случайных чисел! :-D

Comment: вы коварен :-) Вот лишь бы снять с себя ответственность :-)

Answer (score 1):

Открываете вакансии и смотрите, за что больше денег дадут. Не когда-то потом, гипотетически, а с тем, что вы умеете уже сейчас, либо можете по-быстрому выучить. Идёте туда работать (если возьмут, конечно, если нет - смотрите следующую по зарплате вакансию). Работаете, смотрите - нравится вам или нет. Нравится - развиваетесь в этом направлении. Не нравится или надоело - смотрите вакансии за вычетом этого направления, устраиваетесь и т.д. В любом случае и опыт какой-то получите и денег заработаете. А так заранее гадать можно сколько угодно. Пока не поработаете - не узнаете.